# going to new page unless the doc is empty before it

Tags: conditionals, include

Simplyfing quite a lot, I have a document that includes a few files (only if they exist, otherwise it just does nothing).

Then I want to start "something" on a new page.

The issue is that if *none* of the files i wanted to include is actually there, I do not want that "something" to be on page 2 with page 1 taken only by the title. In such a case, I want that "something" to be in page 1, right below the title.

I think i found the following solution (I m definitely not a latex expert):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\title{Sample Doc}
\author{Giulio}

\newboolean{p}


\begin{document}

\setboolean{p}{false}

\maketitle

\IfFileExists{toBeIncluded.tex}
{
    \setboolean{p}{true}
    \input{toBeIncluded.tex}
}
{
    % do nothing
}

\IfFileExists{toBeIncluded2.tex}
{
    \setboolean{p}{true}
    \input{toBeIncluded2.tex}
}
{
    % do nothing
}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{p}}
{
    \newpage
}
{
}

This should start on a new page, unless there is really nothing before it, in which case it should start jst below the title on page one.

\end{document}
```

Is this a decent way out? Is there anything subtle i am missing? Is there a better way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome, i only get one page here.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing there. Why are you working with booleans? Why not simply use a simple `\clearpage` at the end?

Comment: It looks OK to me. (you could add some missing `%` at the ends of lines, but they probably make no difference her as you are (almost certainly) in vertical mode anyway) You could also use `\InputIfFileExists` rather than `\IfFileExists` and a nested `\input` but it doesn't really make any difference)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Hi and thx. You get only one page because the two files do not exist. If at least one of them did, it would be input and then the bool would be true and \newpage would be called. I dont understand your point about \clearpage. Note that the two files could both exist/ both not exist or only one of them could exist. I want "something" to go to new page unless none of toBeIncluded and toBeIncluded2 exist. If they both exist i want no breaks between toBeIncluded and toBeIncluded2.

Comment: @Giulio is each of the input files complete pages? or do you need to input multiple files on to one page. If each input is at a page break you don't need the boolean just do `\input{...}\clearpage` inside each test

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: thx. The input files can be whatsoever I dont know in advance. They can be long or short but i do not want them to break any page. I hope what i m say is clear.. :|

Comment: well as I say, for the general case where the input might be less than a page, your code is fine, not sure if that is really an answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yeah i think it is. Ie if both toBeIncluded1 and toBeIncluded2 exist and span less than a page, i still want "something" to go to a new page. I had tested a bit my code and it looked fine. The purpose of my question was more to see whether there was a more elegant and concise solution.

Comment: @Giulio you could do it in a bit more concise way but it would probably be more obfuscated and harder to understand in 6 months when you come back to it, I think your code is fine. In a document rather than in inner code it is better to be clear than over-concise:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: Yes, this is a *decent* way of doing this.

Second question: Is there a *better* way of doing this? Of course, *better* sometimes is in the eye of the beholder, but I would suggest, to make it easier for you to type it and more flexible for possible future extensions of your document, to wrap your code up into two macros:

- `\myinclude` that does the test whether the file exists, and in case includes the file and sets the value of the boolean.
- `\mynewpage` that checks the value of the boolean, and in case makes a page break and resets the value of the boolean to false (which allows you to use this construction more than once in your code).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test3.tex}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{filecontents*}

\newboolean{p}\setboolean{p}{false}
\newcommand{\myinclude}[1]{\IfFileExists{#1}{\setboolean{p}{true}\input{#1}}{}}
\newcommand{\mynewpage}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{p}}{\clearpage\setboolean{p}{false}}{}}

\title{Sample Doc}
\author{Giulio}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\myinclude{test1.tex}
\myinclude{test2.tex}
\mynewpage

\lipsum[1]

\section{My section}
\myinclude{test3.tex}
\mynewpage
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand your code. I will keep it in mind and possibly use it depending on how complex my document becomes! Thanks a lot again!!